# PHP + Dynamic Sql Queries

Tags: php, sqlite

Image the following data as a result of `SELECT * FROM teams;`

```
Country    Games-W    Games-l    ScoreAverage    RedCards    YellowCards
USA        0.18       0.72       0.67            .01         .08
Mecixo     0.28       0.62       0.77            .06         .01
Italy      0.48       0.52       0.87            .07         .00
Spain      0.78       0.22       0.97            .08         .18
```

I would like to know, how I can have the following.

I know how to implement dynamic sorting for a given column. Using a drop down, the user can select which column to sort on and hit go.

I would like to find a good way to sort on a set of columns without having to write a query for each permutation.

Something like `SELECT *, AVERAGE(Columns) as OverAll FROM teams order by OverAll ASCE;` where Columns is a set of columns.

The questions is: How do I supply the list of columns?
Using html checkbox's? If so, how do I get a list of Columns available (what is the query)?

Are there better approaches to this?

I would prefer if the solution was compatible with SQLite, however, I can change my database if need be.

**EDIT:**

One of the comments said what do you mean by average?

I mean (1/n)SUM(ai):From i= i:{columns selected} to n = Size|columns selected|

`SELECT *, AVERAGE(Game-w, games-l, scoreAverage, redCards, yellowcards) as OverAll FROM teams where Country= 'USA' order by OverAll ASCE;` would result in:

```
Country    Games-W    Games-l    ScoreAverage    RedCards    YellowCards    average
USA        0.18       0.72       0.67            .01         .08            .32
```

Comment: Is you need to show sorted columns on web? Or you just like to sort each columns by just clicking on it from header?

Comment: I can sort a given column on the web. But I need the ability to sort by average of multiple columns

Comment: What do you mean with "average of multiple columns"? Show an example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the below query, you can get the table columns.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name' AND 
      TABLE_NAME = 'table';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, I have not tested in your case, but `AVERAGE` function can be used in `ORDER BY` clause,

```
SELECT * FROM teams where Country= 'USA' 
order by AVG(Game-w, games-l, scoreAverage, redCards, yellowcards) ASC;
```

Comment: @user1048138: please make sure you have removed **E** from very last.